# Blender Union Modifier Doesn't Remove Interior Geometry

Tags: modifiers, error

I'm trying to model a physically based version of the Utah teapot.  The teapot has fluid inside it, which is modeled as a closed manifold:

[image: liquid]

I'm trying to add a [meniscus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meniscus_(liquid)) to the liquid.  I have also modeled these as closed manifolds:

[image: meniscus]

I apply two boolean union operators to join the three together and make a single manifold surface.  However, the result still has geometry inside:

[image: erroneous]

---

[image]

Here is my file.  The fluid (layer 2, active) is unioned with the meniscuses (layer 10+2).  Note: there is an intersection operator also, which is irrelevant (I can flatten it and the checks below are still true).

---

I have tried:

- Cleaning any dead geometry and searching for any non-manifold geometry in all three objects (none, so manifold).
- Recalculating the normals of the meniscus and fluid.
- Inspecting the normals of the meniscus and fluid and confirming they make sense.  As many other questions of this ilk had this as a problem, I checked it thoroughly.
- Setting smooth or flat shading.
- Only doing one meniscus.
- Triangulating everything first.
- Moving the meniscus up/down to see if it's a precision problem.

Comment: This is really not the proper way to work with meshes, Blender is not a CAD software. If you wish future success with mesh based modeling you should drop the Booleans, use adequate modelling techniques and [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com)